# A couple of quick questions related to "Messrs"

Tags: pronunciation

How is "Messrs" pronounced?

The meaning is the plural of "Mister", right?

Does that mean that "Misters" is not a word?

Is "Messrs" a word that is more commonly used in England than the United States?

Comment: Messrs is often used by (British Commonwealth) lawyers and proprietors of older establishements, as in "Messrs Jones and Hawthorne". It's still very common in some parts of the world. Also, as a point of interest, some lawyers also like to use the postfix Esq. as in "Richard Jones, Esq."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is pronounced *Mess-ers* derived from the French plural *messieurs*, while *Mr* comes from *master*.  Its use is correct but fairly uncommon: *Mr Smith and Mr Jones* is more usual than *Messrs Smith and Jones*; *Misters Smith and Jones* is extremely rare while *Mrs Smith and Jones* would suggest a sex-change.

Comment: In that vein, do you know how "Mme." is pronounced?  Do English speakers usually pronounce it "Mademoiselle", or some other way?

Comment: @Rhodri No, it is I who is in fact wrong -- Mlle. is the true abbreviation for mademoiselle (I just looked it up).  Incidentally, what I was really asking was whether people said the whole thing out loud, or just mumbled "Em-Em-Eee", or something.

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean that "Misters" is not a word?

The plural of Mister is used; you can find sentences like the following:

> The gold medals they won at earlier races aren't the only thing that Misters Hedrick and Cheek have in common.

> Is "Messrs" a word that is more commonly used in England than the United States?

The NOAD describes *Messrs.* as dated or chiefly British.

Comment: And so... what is "NOAD" ?

Comment: It's the _New Oxford American Dictionary_, the Oxford dictionary for American.

Comment: Ah ha!  I figured it had to be New Oxford, but the "A" was a big mystery.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you would find "Messrs" used in speech except for comic effect. Its use now is pretty well restricted to addressing envelopes - and probably only from old-fashioned organisations.